# Laravel - Use Middleware with a token to get temporary file access

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I want to allow an user to open a video in an external app.
For the user I'm creating a temporary (random) token.
I'm aware of the risks (user can share link/token), maybe want to add an IP/device limiter. Since this is nothing serious/home project, I'd just want to learn what's best practice when dealing with middleware. :)

```
class VideoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param AssetRequest $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public function show(AssetRequest $request)
    {
        // Get token, valid against user_id, asset
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to use a middleware instead?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthenticateWithToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Valid token here

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Or is this not the task of the middleware?
Should I use the `guest` middleware instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you can do this in middleware.

Comment: I'm trying to add a own request class: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateWithToken::handle() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\CheckTokenRequest, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /path/to/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php on line 149`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware) on this is the place to go.

So for example you would do something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!isTokenExpired($token)) { // logic to check if token has access
            return redirect('myTempAppRouterNameHere');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then, make sure you checkout the registration section and implement anything that applies to you. I think using middleware is the easier way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Here are a couple of good resources:

Laravel 5.5: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-55-create-custom-middleware-exampleexample.html

https://medium.com/@Sharad35386442/laravel-5-5-middleware-complete-tutorial-44d8f4d61c4b

Laravel 5.1: https://tutorialedge.net/php/laravel/laravel-5-middleware-tutorial/

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/custom-requests-in-middleware

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to create a custom request in the middelware?
I also need to check if the exists.